# Sveltekit form actions with super forms clearing input before post

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, zod, sveltekit-superforms

I have a register form that takes an email and password. It is validated using zod and SuperForms. When I submit the form the data from the form is cleared before requesting the form action defined in +page.server.ts.

How do I fix this to pass the form data to `+page.server.ts` properly?

When clicking submit a request can be seen in the network calls and when logged in the `+page.server.ts` gives response

```json
Request (0 KB) {
  method: "POST",
  url: "http://localhost:5173/register?/register",
  headers: Headers {
    "host": "localhost:5173",
    "connection": "keep-alive",
    "content-length": "152",
    "accept": "application/json",
    "content-type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryDpiWF58YTcB17kNP",
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
    "origin": "http://localhost:5173",
    "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
    "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
    "referer": "http://localhost:5173/register?/register",
    "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br, zstd",
    "accept-language": "en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8",
    "sec-ch-ua": "\"Not A(Brand\";v=\"99\", \"Google Chrome\";v=\"121\", \"Chromium\";v=\"121\"",
    "x-sveltekit-action": "true",
    "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
    "sec-ch-ua-platform": "\"Windows\"",
    "sec-fetch-site": "same-origin",
  }
  ReadableStream {
    locked: [Getter],
    cancel: [Function: cancel],
    getReader: [Function: getReader],
    pipeTo: [Function: pipeTo],
    pipeThrough: [Function: pipeThrough],
    tee: [Function: tee],
    values: [Function: values],
    [Symbol(Symbol.asyncIterator)]: [Function: lazyAsyncIterator],
  }
}
{
  id: "1p3ituu",
  valid: false,
  posted: true,
  errors: {
    email: [ "Please enter a valid email address" ],
    password: [ "Password must be at least 8 characters long" ],
  },
  data: {
    email: "",
    password: "",
  },
}
```

this shows that the email and password aren't being passed to the server.

I know that the data is entering the form properly as the values can be seen here in the superforms debug view

[image]

## Code

### register-form.svelte

```html
<script lang="ts">
    import { Label } from "$lib/components/ui/label";
    import { Input } from "$lib/components/ui/input";
    import { Button } from "$lib/components/ui/button";
    import SuperDebug from "sveltekit-superforms";
    import {
        registerFormSchema,
        type RegisterFormSchema,
    } from "./register-form";
    import {
        type SuperValidated,
        type Infer,
        superForm,
    } from "sveltekit-superforms";
    import { zodClient } from "sveltekit-superforms/adapters";

    export let data: { form: SuperValidated<RegisterFormSchema> };
    const form = superForm(data.form, {
        validators: zodClient(registerFormSchema),
        multipleSubmits: "prevent",
    });

    const { form: formData, errors, enhance } = form;
</script>

<form method="POST" use:enhance>
    <div class="form-sections flex gap-4 flex-col">
        <div class="form-input flex flex-col gap-2">
            <Label for="email">Email</Label>
            <Input type="email" bind:value={$formData.email} />
            {#if $errors.email}<span class="invalid text-red-600"
                    >{$errors.email}</span
                >{/if}
        </div>
        <div class="form-input flex flex-col gap-2">
            <Label for="password">Password</Label>
            <Input type="password" bind:value={$formData.password} />
            {#if $errors.password}<span class="invalid text-red-600"
                    >{$errors.password}</span
                >{/if}
        </div>
        <Button on:click|once type="submit" class="w-full"
            >Create account</Button
        >
    </div>
</form>

<SuperDebug data={formData} />
```

### +page.server.ts

```js
import type { PageServerLoad, Actions } from './$types';
import { fail } from '@sveltejs/kit';
import { superValidate } from 'sveltekit-superforms';
import { zod } from 'sveltekit-superforms/adapters';
import { registerFormSchema } from './register-form';
import { unauthenticatedRequest } from '@/services/api-service/apiService';

export const load: PageServerLoad = async () => {
    return {
        form: await superValidate(zod(registerFormSchema))
    };
}

export const actions: Actions = {
    register: async ({ request }) => {
        console.log("register action called")
        // console.log(request);
        const form = await superValidate(request, zod(registerFormSchema));
        console.log(form);
        if (!form.valid) {
            console.log("form not valid")
            return fail(400, {
                form,
            });
        }

        const { email, password } = form.data;
        console.log(email, password);
        const response = await unauthenticatedRequest('POST', 'auth/register', {
            email,
            password,
        });

        console.log(response);
        switch (response.status) {
            case 201:
                return {
                    status: 201,
                    headers: {
                        'set-cookie': response.headers.get('set-cookie'),
                    },
                    form
                };
            case 409:
                return {
                    status: 409,
                    body: {
                        error: 'User already exists',
                    },
                    form
                };
        }
        return {
            form,
        };
    },
};
```

### +page.svelte

```html
// page definition imports Register form and uses it in a card
// ...
            </div>
        </div>
        <RegisterForm {data} />
    </Card.Content>
</Card.Root>
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe not the root of the problem but I noticed:

- Your `<form>` doesn't specify the name of the action it wants to call, and you are using a named action: `register`. I just tested this, and for me, it gives me an error if I try to send a form without a name when the server doesn't have a `default`.

  - Either modify `<form>` to contain `action="?/register"`
  - Or in +page.server.ts change the name of the action to `default`.

https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/form-actions

Also, try debugging the form without Zod. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately, that was just a bug that I had left in when trying different things to make it work. I do like your suggestion of trying without Zod so will see how that goes.

Answer (score 0):

The form was coming through as empty as the input fields didn't have a `name` property set so when getting the form data the form didn't now which value to set.

```html
 <Input
     name="password"
     type="password"
     bind:value={$formData.password}
 />
```